# iPhone: Animation transition types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

Where can I find a list of available core animation transition types?
For example, there is 'UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight' but where can I find what the other ones are called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined at UIViewAnimationTransition section of [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_203).

```
typedef enum {
 UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
 UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
 UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
 UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
 UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```